# Почему в коде два раза выводится console.log

Tags: javascript, функции

Никак не пойму логику работы этого кода:
по сути я пишу консоль.лог один раз, почему он выводит перед ним ещё текст: ***I want to eat apple*** как это работает объясните? Функцию то я не вызываю , а просто присваиваю её переменно а.

```
function foodDemand (food) {
          console.log("I want to eat" + " " + food);  
    }

    var a = foodDemand("apple");
    console.log("apple");

    // -> I want to eat apple
    // -> apple
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Давайте по порядку. В JavaScript функция -- это [объект первого класса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0). Вы можете выполнять с ней различные действия.

Можно сохранить функцию в переменную

```
var f = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Можно передать функцию в функцию, как аргумент:

```
function runner(task) {
    task('foo bar baz');
}
```

Можно вернуть функию из функции как результат:

```
function builder() {
    return function() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Можно создать функцию во время выполнения программы:

```
var f;

if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    f = function() {
        console.log('low');
    };
} else {
    f = function() {
        console.log('high');
    };
}
```

А еще, в отличии от других объектов первого класса, функцию можно вызывать. Для этого существует специальный синтаксис `()` (круглые скобки):

```
var f = function() {/* ... */}
// Вот так функция вызывается
f();
```

---

Теперь вернемся к вашему вопросу. Вот тут:

```
function foodDemand (food) {
    console.log("I want to eat" + " " + food);  
}
```

Вы объявляете функцию, которая доступна по идентификатору `foodDemand`.

Говоря

> Функцию то я не вызываю , а просто присваиваю её переменно а.

Вы ошибаетесь. Вы как раз вызываете функцию и присваиваете **результат** ее выполнения переменной `a`.

Присваивание функции переменной `a` должно иметь вид:

```
// Обратите внимание на отсутствие круглых скобок.
var a = foodDemand;
```

Comment: Возможно, ТС хотел получить в переменной замыкание, вызывающее `foodDemand` с аргументом `"Apple"`?

Comment: нет замыкание я не хотел получить. У меня вызывает проблему понимание вот это выражение: var a = foodDemand("apple"); - Я вызвал функцию она исполнилась и результат я записал в а.  Кажется после разъяснений мне стало понятно. спасибо всем!

Answer (score 4):

Как раз в данном коде, вы вызываете функцию `foodDemand`. При этом, поскольку функция ни чего не возвращает, то значение переменной `a == undefined`, в чем легко убедится, вызвав `console.log(a)`.

Если вам нужно что-бы переменная `а` была функцией, то тогда надо записать так (без параметров):

```
var a = foodDemand;
a("apple"); // I want to eat apple
```

Answer (score 4):

Напротив, функцию вы вызываете. И она при вызове пишет в консоль.

Чтобы присвоить переменной `a` функцию `foodDemand` используйте следующий код

```
function foodDemand (food) {
      console.log("I want to eat" + " " + food);  
}

var a = foodDemand;
console.log("apple");
```

и там где требуется вызовите

```
a('apple');
```

не забудьте, что локальная переменная `a` будет доступна только внутри того модуля, где вы ее объявили. чтобы сделать ее доступной глобально, можно не использовать `var` при объявлении и тогда переменная будет доступна на странице как свойство объекта `window`

Answer (score 0):

Да что вы парнишку загрузили))

**1. Ты вызываешь функцию foodDemand, которая записывает в консоль текст (по условию)**

**2. Ты вызываешь console.log, которая пишет текст в консоль**

Comment: Для меня это вполне нормальные разъяснения. Я сюда и прихожу для того чтобы понять суть проблемы, опытные товарищи помогают это сделать. Разъясняя всё по порядку с самого начала. Именно в этом и задумка сайта. Что навести человека на верные размышления. То что я вызываю функцию, и она записывает в консоль я и так прекрасно вижу. Но вот почему это происходило понять не мог. Пока не спросил)